# from an Asterisk server via Twilio then return them to Asterisadding a value to the cust header in the proces,would disconnect the call after the tx

Tags: triggers

am looking to receive communications from an Asterisk server via Twilio and then return them to the same Asterisk server, adding a value to the custom header in the process. Therefore, I would like to disconnect the call after the transfer. If possible, I would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this using the REFER clause

Nothingjnjfgj;klenl;